# add headerView from nib to UICollectionView swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

**Problem State**: 
I need to add various Header(like category) for UICollectionView.how can i achieve like this.

[image]

any Help will be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
 // in viewDidload

self.UICollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId")

// use delegate delegate        
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath)
        var lblHeaher : UILabel!

    // as header is dequing that's why we need to check if label is there then no need to init label again and again
    if header.viewWithTag(101) == nil {
        lblHeaher = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: servicesCollectionView.frame.width, height: 40))
        lblHeaher.tag = 101
    }else{
        lblHeaher = header.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    }


    lblHeaher.text = "category \(indexPath.row)"
    lblHeaher.textAlignment = .left
    lblHeaher.textColor = UIColor.white
    lblHeaher.font = UIFont.init(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 20)!

    header.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    header.addSubview(lblHeaher)
    return header
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: 40)
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return numberofSection
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have `XIB` with label and you want to show as header of collection view

first register `XIB` in ViewDidLoad

using

```
open func register(_ viewClass: Swift.AnyClass?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind elementKind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

i.e

```
    collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "NIB", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header")
```

After that you can setup your section collection view like this

```
extension ViewController :UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 5;
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        if kind.isEqual(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! MySectionHeaderClass
            cell.title = "MyString "
            return cell
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

//MAKE YOUR  Collection view item width to full screen
```

Hope it is clear to you

Answer (score 0):

After, Override the function determine `indexPath.section` and return the title.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String!
```

And, You have to make `UIColectionView` as subview of `UITableViewCell`,
All the `UICollectionViewCell` setup will be managed in the `UITableViewCell`